# How to make foreign key update based on parent

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have two tables, and I've made a relation using the Designer between the id column of my first table to the user_id column of my second table. Where and how do I add code or do something so that when, for example, the parent (id) is deleted, the user_id values which correspond to the deleted id will also be deleted? I tried deleting one of the registered ids, but the corresponding rows in the child table didn't get deleted.

I've done some searching, but I'm still very confused.

Thank you.

Note: I'm experimenting with MySQL and PHP, and this is for a little blog I'm making.

Answer (score 0):

Please add an `ON DELETE` referential action to the foreign key constraint.

More details could be found here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

For your case, `ON DELETE CASCADE` should be fine.

Comment: Where would I type this in when using phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

1. set **id** from first table as primary key

   CREATE TABLE tbl_first(id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, name varchar(20))
2. create your second table as **tbl_second**

   CREATE TABLE tbl_second(id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, fk_id int)
3. add **constraint** like this:

   alter table tbl_second

   add constraint fk_first

   foreign key tbl_second(fk_id)

   references tbl_first(id)

   on delete cascade

it seem SQL Server and mySql are a little different, but it should work, i test it in mySQL

Comment: whit this code, when you want to insert in tbl_second, you should choose from value of "id" in tbl_first
and
when you delete a row in tbl_first, if you have a child in tbl_second, it delete too,

Comment: Thank you for all the help! :) Sorry it took me a while to get back to you.

Comment: The tables were successfully added and altered, but on deletion of a row from the first table, the row with the same ID in the second table is not deleted.